# Fiware: INTEGRATING GRAFANA WITH ORION USING MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, real-time, grafana, fiware, fiware-orion

for some time now I have been working together with my research team using different fiware components. After putting on ORION, using MongoDB for writing context data, I thought of using Grafana to show in real time data sent to ORION and stored on Mongo (For example data from a sensor). I was wondering what would be the best method to connect Grafana to ORION, considering that the free version does not offer a connector to MongoDB. Currently through a plugin, on Grafana, I can call the API exposed by the context broker to retrieve the data and then build the tables and the different charts. I wanted to know if this is a good practice or there are better ways, thanks!

Comment: Best Practice FIWARE-Grafana bridge is described in [this webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gaa23hC0teo). You should avoid using the underlying Mongo-DB database and query entities via NGSI.

Comment: If you want temporal data displayed either use QuantumLeap and the CrateDB Grafana Sink, or use the NGSI-LD Temporal interface as the basis of your queries